Is there an operator to do a "tap only if" in RxJS? A conditional tap action
observable.pipe(
  tap((booleanValue) => {
    if (booleanValue) {
      doSomething();
    }
  }),
)

Is there a best practice or a better way to do this?
I don't want to filter because the data still needs to stream, only the tap action is conditional.

This looks elegant :) why complicate it

@NarenMurali just in case an operator exists to do it directly :)

Your second best alternative after writing what you proposed it to implement a custom rxjs operator yourself.
For example
function conditionalTap(conditionFn, tapFn) {
  return (source$) => source$.pipe(
    tap(value => {
      if (conditionFn(value)) {
        tapFn(value);
      }
    })
  );
}

source$
  .pipe(
    map(x => x * 2),
    conditionalTap(
      value => value > 5,    // Condition function
      value => console.log(`Value greater than 5: ${value}`) // Tap function
    )
  )
  .subscribe(value => console.log(`Output: ${value}`));

